# Laravel Exception Handling

Tags: laravel

i am using laravel 5.4.when i have save the survey some error shown
AlgoliaException
**Operations quota exceeded, change plan to get more Operations**
Laravel 5.4
My code is

```
$request->user()->surveys()->create($request->all())
```

Comment: Is there some sort of event on your survey object that uses an external api?

Comment: You're over your usage limit with Algolia... "Operations quota exceeded, change plan to get more Operations"... They want money from you.